# Making donut without updating id in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, sql-server

I wont to make a donut out of an polygon in MapInfo. I store my data in Sql Server 2008 R2 and access it as a linked table. In SQL Server the Id-column is an Identity column that is used to as a primary key and is related as a foreign key in other tables.

My problem is when I try to make the donut the Id is reset to zero and when I save the changes it gets an new Id in the database, since I use the Id to connect to other tables you can se the problem. Is there a way to avoid resetting the Id?

Regards
Ulrik

Comment: how are you trying to make your donut? By using the "Set Target" and "Erase"?